# Open source library for voice based command activation

Tags: c++, user-interface, audio, speech-recognition

I need to develop an embedded device which can identify voice commands and then effect an operation. I plan to use C++. Which open source libraries can I use for speech processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pocketsphinx library is designed specifically for embedded low-resource devices

See

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Read the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial